# View that lists nodes with link to downloadable file

Tags: views, blocks, nodes

I have a content type called "Learning Material" and it has two fields: title of type text and file of type file.

I have a block view that lists all Learning Material.  When I click on the link for a learning material, it takes me to a page with a link to download the file.  I want to have the download automatically happen when I click on the link in the block view.  Is this possible?

Comment: sounds like your view is listing each node of Learning Material in the fields area.  Have you tried having the file field listed in there instead, eg, having the title in one field, and the file field next to it in the next?

Comment: @jimajamma - ok and if i don't want the title field, then i just use css to hide the title?   And if anyone ever lands on the page fo rthe file, i should do a 301 redirect to the file?

Comment: I think you might be overcomplicating things here.  You can use the Views UI to show or not show the title when configuring the field.

Comment: What about if I want to show the title, but the title shoudl link directly to the downloadable file?  Will the views ui allow me to program such a rule? (Ie. never show the page with a link to the file, just download the file).

Comment: you can use views to rewrite just about anything.  click on the little wheel/gear/round config widget and you can see all you can do